# Could a person who has served time for 2nd degree murder later be charged with 1st degree murder if their co-defendant gets a new trial?

Tags: murder, double-jeopardy

If someone was charged with 1st degree murder but got it got dropped to 2nd degree with a plea of 10 yrs, and their co-defendant got a new trial, could they then be charged with 1st degree murder even after serving time for 2nd degree?

Comment: I have edited this to make it a neutral question about law and voted to reopen.

Comment: Any particular jurisdiction?  Mine doesn't have "degrees" of murder.

Answer (score 1):

> could they then be charged with 1st degree murder even after serving
> time for 2nd degree?

No.

A conviction for murder precludes a new prosecution for murder involving the same victim, as a result of constitutional double jeopardy protections and also other legal doctrines.

Comment: I suppose that would be not just a conviction for murder, but a conviction for manslaughter or negligent killing as well. Or being found not guilty.